# Reaction of fumaric acid and performic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

Performic acid ($\ce{CH2O3}$) has strong oxidizing properties. So when it reacts with fumaric acid, is this the product (2,3-dihydroxybutanedioic acid) that I should expect?

[image]

Comment: My first thought would be epoxidation, but I don't suppose dihydroxylation is out of the question.

Comment: Peracids usually epxydize compounds with C-C double bonds

Comment: Wiki claims that performic acid is capable of "epoxidation, hydroxylation and oxidation reactions".

Comment: Do the three double bonds in fumaric acid help to stabilize the fumaric acid by interactions of the π-bonds? If so, does this affect which product is preferred?